# How to add horizontal spacing between two Spannables?

Tags: android, spannablestring, android-spannable

I have a custom TextView that combines two pieces of text and have a spacing variable.

```kotlin
class MyCustomTextView() {

  var label: String
  var value: String
  var spacingBetweenLabelAndValue: Int = 0

  // ...
}
```

Each one have their own style and are concatenated. Example:

- label -> "Name:"
- value -> "John"

```kotlin
this.text = Spanny(label, *labelTextSpannables)
      .append(value, *valueTextSpannables)
```

which in the end is resulting in "Name:John"

I want to add an extra spacing (`spacingBetweenLabelAndValue`) between those two strings.

```
"Name:(spacing here)John"
```

Is there a way to do this using Spannable?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SpannableStringBuilder("label")
.append(String.format("%1$" + spacingBetweenLabelAndValue + "s", ""))
.append(SpannableString("value"))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying but that answer does not involve the use of `dps` for the spacing.